# GetObject fails on a text cursor

Tags: c, windows, bitmap, cursor, gdi

I'm trying to fetch the cursor bitmap in order to compute a snapshot with the mouse cursor.

It works fine with the standard cursor (IE. the arrow) but it fails as soon as the cursor becomes a text cursor.
Basically I'm doing this :

```
//Fetching the cursor handle
GetCursorInfo( &m_infos );
m_handle = m.infos.hCursor;
//Fetching cursor info
ICONINFO    infos;
HICON   icon = CopyCursor( m_handle );
GetIconInfo( icon, &infos );
BITMAP  bitInfos;
if ( GetObject( infos.hbmColor, sizeof( bitInfos ), &bitInfos ) == 0 )
{
    qDebug() << "Error N:" << GetLastError();
}
```

The problem is, GetObject() AND GetLastError() return 0... so i'm not abble to know which is the error...

I'm running this code on Win7, using QtCreator and MingW.

Any idea, clue, would be much appreciated !!
Thanks a lot in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "text cursor". It's called a caret, and it's dealt with totally differently than the mouse pointer. See [Using Carets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648398%28VS.85%29.aspx) on MSDN for more info.

Comment: I think chouquette was referring to the 'I-beam' cursor, not the caret?

Comment: @Julien, you may be right. I may have been mistaken based on the wording used.

Answer (score 0):

`infos.hbmColor` is probably `NULL`. [MSDN says for `ICONINFO.hbmColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648052.aspx):

> A handle to the icon color bitmap. This member can be optional if this structure defines a black and white icon.

Usually, the text cursor (IDC_IBEAM) is defined by using only color inversion and transparency, explaining the fact that `hbmColor` is `NULL`. You should always apply `hbmMask` to the optional `hbmColor`.